# How to upload the full-resolution pictures taken by Instagram to Flickr?

Tags: iphone, photos, flickr

When [Instagram](http://instagr.am/) takes a pictures, it send a lower resolution version to Flickr, but saves the full resolution in the Camera Roll. Right now, I am:

1. Taking picture and letting Instagram send the lower resolution version to Flickr, so something is available online right away.
2. Later on, transfer the pictures to my Mac (through iCloud or sync), and replace one by one the pictures on Flickr with the full resolution version I have locally.

This last step is time consuming and error prone. Ideally, I'd like Instagram to upload the full resolution picture for me when over wifi. But short of that, what would you do to streamline this process? Maybe "there is an app for that"?

<sup>As a side-note, you might wonder why I am using Instagram, and not taking pictures with the Camera app or the Flickr app:</sup>

- <sup>I like to enter a title right away, just after taking the picture (so the Camera app wouldn't cut it).</sup>
- <sup>I like the fact that the version of the picture sent right away is lower resolution, not to kill my limited mobile quota (so the Flickr app wouldn't cut it).</sup>
- <sup>(I also like the square format: IMHO, it makes framing simpler, and creates pictures that just looks better for online viewing.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Posterous Spaces](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/posterous/id394252521?mt=8) app to save full resolution photos from the roll to the web and have that linked to push to flickr. You could also use the native [flickr](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flickr/id328407587?mt=8) app to pick them from the roll.

Comment: Don't forget to disable the Instagram push to flickr. Much simpler to just use posterous. You can even just email the pictures to post@posterous.com once you've set up your account. No need to use their app unless you want to override the names or add more pictures than one email can contain.

Comment: With Posterous Spaces or the Flickr app, I can have a full resolution picture posted to Flickr, but that doesn't solve my problem: having a lower resolution posted right away (over 3G) and then replaced by the full resolution picture when I am over WiFi, does it?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't know of shipping apps that make use of the [replace a photo API from flickr](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/replace.api.html) so you are indeed correct this won't happen with the tools I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I used [PicBackMan's migrate tool](http://www.picbackman.com/picbackman-for-mac-os/) to move all my Instagram Pictures to Flickr account.All I did was, associated Instagram & Flickr accounts in the desktop application and it went through like a breeze.

I highly recommend it.